# Android Studio Emulator is stuck and always loading

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

when i start my emulator on a basic program like "hello world"
it is not starting and keeps loading for a very very long time and not starting at all, and only the progress bar keeps moving.
even when my android studio is installed on my SSD 250 samsung.
please if someone can help me start this thing.

i attached my data and the situation that is stuck on:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio want the minimum **8GB RAM** for your Laptop/Pc and 16 GB for smoothly run. Due to Low RAM it take to much time for Start .

See Below link for system Requirment-
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html